# Context path on multiple subpath

Tags: uri, 7

So, I have a `hook_menu` creating a page like `category/page`. I allow two parameters on this URL. It looks like this :

```
// Menu declaration
$items['category/page'] = ...

// Page argument
'page arguments' => array('myModule_form', 2, 3),
```

So, I can have URL like this `category/page/param1/param2`.

I want to have context that works on all the possible URL. So I tried multiple solutions for the path of the context : `category/*`, `category/*/*` and `category*`. But, in every case, the context only works for `category/page`. Just adding an arguments breaks it.

Any solution?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you adding multiple routing items (e.g. `$items['category/page/%param1/%param2'] = ...`,  and `$items['category/%page/%param1/%param2'] = ...`) in your `hook_menu` implementation?

Comment: @ShawnConn I've edited my question with how my `hook_menu` is done.